# How to display very small image with 100% zoom with Python opencv

Tags: python, opencv, zooming, display

I just wanted to display a small simple image.

```
import numpy as np
import cv2
a = np.zeros([64, 64], np.float32)
a[12, 31] = 1
cv2.imshow('test', a)
cv2.waitKey(0)
```

[image: The resulting image: two dots are here]

I just add one dot, but two dots are shown.

The problem is caused by the zoom rate.
I checked the display image size is (71, 71).
How can I display this image correctly?

Thank you for your wisdom.

---

Environment:

```
Ubuntu 18.04.2 LTS
Python 3.6.8
opencv-python (4.1.0.25)
```

---

additional :

[image: The resulting image: two dots are here]

When I pull down my mouse's wheel, I can see the message that 'Zoom:100%'. But actually, the zoom rate is not 100%. TWO DOTS are still shown and the displayed image size is (71, 71).

cv2.resizeWindow doesn't work.

---

addition:

[image: The resulting image: two dots are here]

When I ran same code on Windows 10, I could see correct display. It is exact 100% zoom rate.

Answer (score -1):

You can always use cv2.resize() to change the size of the image to what you want.

```
height = 64
dim = (width, height)

resized = cv2.resize(a, dim, interpolation = cv2.INTER_AREA)
```

Comment: The image's size is already correct. I'm just saying about display. I need exact 100% zoom.

Comment: On what grounds do you know that the zoom rate is wrong? If the image is the right size, isn't the zoom rate 100% then?

Comment: As the code I shown, I specified the image size as (64, 64) but the display size is (71, 71) and there is no way to make it as (64, 64), 100% zoom rate.

Comment: How did you measure the size of the display image? You never specified that

Comment: You can download the image that I uploaded. And check the size with any imaging tools. Above all, you see the TWO DOTS on the screenshot, but I just draw one dot by the code. Can you explain why two dots are displayed?

Comment: Well you already said that the problem is caused by the zoom rate so you were obviously not asking for an explanation about that. And since the zoom rate is 100% there is nothing wrong with the zoom rate. The images you upload are not the original image but a snapshot of the window you show them in, with this it is not possible to check the size. Your question should be rephrased

Comment: I can try it myself tomorrow when I have python and opencv installed on the computer, here I just have c# and visual studio.  Will get back to you :)